# docker ps command's filter with NOT condition

Tags: docker, docker-cli

I am using minkube as docker engine. So I can get the many container instances related minikube containers with 'docker ps' command. I want to see the containers without them.

minikube containers's name start with 'k8s-bra-bra' so I want to filter using that.

`docker ps` command support `--filter` options but I don't know how to set NOT condition like `docker ps --filter "name!=k8s*"`. please help. thanks.

Comment: After going though the documentation i could find that docker ps will be able to only support type=value. But you could use grep -v flag to achieve this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took a look at the Docker documentation and there doesn't seem to be a default way of setting a NOT condition like that.
However, you can use the `grep` command to do the filtering:

```
docker ps | grep -v "k8s"
```

The `-v` option tells `grep` to exclude all the matching patterns.